# Getting CUSTOM_RECORD_COLLISION when saving a NetSuite custom record in SuiteScript

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm not sure where I have gone wrong here. I trying to keep track of pages our customers are on by updating a field on a custom record. When a page is submitted it updates the field and when the page is loaded it updates the field again. However I am getting CUSTOM_RECORD_COLLISION on some of them (not all). I am using the following code to update the field. I am doing it in a loop but break out after the first record as I only want the latest pagetracker record.

```
for(key in pagetrackerARR){
    var pagetracker = pagetrackerARR[key];
    record.load({
        type : 'customrecord_pagetracker ',
        id : pagetracker .id
    }).setValue({
        fieldId : 'custrecord_cw_max_page',
        value : value
    }).save();
    break;
}
```

I thought that if I loaded the record each time, it would not run into these errors as it's the latest version of this record.

Comment: could you verify your _recordType_ that you are passing to `record.load` is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Most of the time it works. We just have a handful of times it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're updating the field when the page is submitted and then again when the page is loaded, it could be that the record is still being written to during the save/submit when you attempt to write to it again during load. If you really need to handle both situations, try using `record.submitFields` instead of loading the whole record. You could also do the writing to the record on page load after a delay using `setTimeout`.